# Which is faster to access a file in android, sdcard or system partition?

Tags: android, performance, file, android-sdcard

I have one simple question. If i have one file in system partition of android and if i copy the same file on sdcard, which will be faster to access?

Please answer this question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The difference will be negligible. In any case, most newer devices have just one storage onboard the device, which is partitioned. In such devices, the need to access a separate SD Card goes away, as the memory is the same as the system storage.

On devices with an SD Card, there may be a very minute delay in accessing the file, but it will be negligible in pretty much any scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Actually i have one application that has one video file in system partition. app copies this file to sdcard and then it access this file from sdcard, why so? Even it can directly access that file from system parition?

Comment: @VicJordan Maybe its a prepackaged file in its assets folder, and it wants to be able to write to it, which is not possible if the file is prepackaged.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to really notice the access speed difference between accessing file from internal memory and SD Card. 
With internal memory you will get added advantage of a security as it won't be accessible for other applications or you cannot access it by mounting.

Comment: Yes there is more security at system partition even file can not be deleted

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Internal phone memory 
because disk management(for phone ) is always better for internal memory as compared to SD card, So it is faster to access internal memory but you will not be able to notice the because difference is in mili seconds

With internal memory you will get advantage like user can't see your file until unless device is not rooted.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the time difference is not noticeable. However, a simple law of physics (and EE) will tell you that the longer the distance is (in this case the I/O bus), the longer it will take in time. Thus, the SDCard is slower than anything on the motherboard, even though it is measured in miliseconds.

I have found the SDCard is best used for static storage of your media files, and apps should be installed on the phone making them run as fast as possible, even though you can move some apps to the SDCard.

Answer (score 0):

The speed is not noticeable unless you are coping the very large video files. The SD card speed is measured by class like:(Class 4, 6 or 10), the class 10 have higher speed as 10MB/S and class 2 have speed around 2MB/S. So, for good class of SD card, the speed gap is less. However, normally phone memory is faster than the SD card.